# Facebook-like questions

Tags: facebook, survey

i'm looking for a website with a functionality similar to the "questions" app on facebook, the main idea is to post a list of options for the users to vote on which one they prefer or to add their own suggestions, I wanted to take a look to some online survey solutions but no luck so far (I don't want to buy anything without knowing if its going to work), embedding would be nice but it's not essential, workarounds are also welcome

cheers,

Will

Answer (score 0):

You need something like [micropoll](http://www.micropoll.com/)?

Comment: Hi Benjaming, 

it's not quite what i need, want i want to do it's post a list of activities and the user will vote which activities they want to do and i want them to be able to propose new activities and the other users should be able to vote for those as well, so pretty much the same as the facebook questions,

thanks for your reply :D

Will

Answer (score 0):

ideascale.com, does what i was looking for :D